# How to Develop a Desktop Static Library to support Windows Store App

Tags: c++, porting

I have to migrate a Desktop Static Library (written in VC++ 2010) to support Windows Store App (written in VC++ 2012). The problem is that Desktop Static Library includes many low level i/o functions, for example: open, fopen, read, write, seek that are not supported on Windows Store App. The questions are:

1) Can I use open, fopen, write functions on Windows Store App. If it is Yes, where location files can be written?

2) Which functions can alternated open, fopen, read, write, seek functions?

Thank for help.

Comment: All of those functions are callable from a Windows Store app (well, `open`, `fopen`, `read`, and `write` are; there is no `seek` in the CRT, but `fseek` and friends are available).  The entire C Standard Library should be available for use by a Windows Store app, and many of the Visual C++-specific CRT functions are also available.

Comment: Compile & build is OK, but when I use open, fopen functions for writing (reading is OK), it always returns false (may be the reason is access permission). Where location can I use with open, fopen functions?

Comment: Have you tried with visual studio 2012? I was having a lot of issues with VS 2010, but are all gone now that I'm using VS 2012. Just a suggestion.